# How can I determine safe surfing conditions from a surf report for a beginner?

Tags: injuries, surfing

I'm not a strong swimmer, and I'm not positive I could swim back to shore if my leash were to snap. I understand this is a major risk, and I'm taking steps to mitigate it (I've begun private swimming lessons, and I practice at a local pool a few times a week), but this is my last summer in the West Coast and I'm not willing to wait on the sidelines and watch the summer go by.

So far I'd been looking at the swell height, *e.g.* 1-2 ft. today for my area [on Magic Seaweed](http://magicseaweed.com/Solana-Beach-Surf-Report/294/):

[image]

I've also learned that waves seem calmer during high tide (and please correct me if that's a faulty or oversimplified assumption).

But last week I went on a 1-2 ft. day during high tide and the waves turned out to be randomly sized with occasional massive (4-5 ft.) sets. And the water was so choppy, I felt I was being rocked from all sides and struggling to keep balance on my board. What went wrong in the forecast? Or more likely, my reading of it?

Do the secondary and tertiary swells have to do with choppiness? Should I read more into some of the other stats, like swell periods or wind speed?

**In short, how should I read a surf report, as a beginning surfer and weak swimmer, and what, if any, are some danger signs I should look out for?**